# How do I close, then re-open an Xodus database?

Tags: kotlin, xodus

I implemented a simple example creating, closing and opening a database:

```
package whatever

import jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.Entity
import kotlinx.dnq.XdEntity
import kotlinx.dnq.XdModel
import kotlinx.dnq.XdNaturalEntityType
import kotlinx.dnq.store.container.StaticStoreContainer
import kotlinx.dnq.util.initMetaData
import kotlinx.dnq.xdRequiredStringProp
import org.junit.Test
import java.nio.file.Files

class UnclosedTest {
    private val dbFolder = Files.createTempDirectory(null).toFile()

    private val store = StaticStoreContainer.init(
            dbFolder = dbFolder,
            environmentName = "store"
    ).also {
        XdModel.registerNodes(
                Bogus
        )

        initMetaData(XdModel.hierarchy, it)
    }

    @Test
    fun `the database is unlocked when store is closed`() {
        store.use { store ->
            store.transactional {
                Bogus.new {
                    text = "gnarf"
                }
            }
        }

        assert(dbFolder.exists())
        assert(dbFolder.isDirectory)
        assert(dbFolder.resolve("xd.lck").exists())

        PersistentEntityStores.newInstance(dbFolder)
        // ^^^ throws
    }

    class Bogus(entity: Entity) : XdEntity(entity) {
        companion object : XdNaturalEntityType<Bogus>()

        var text by xdRequiredStringProp()
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, this test fails with a `Can't acquire environment lock` exception:

```
Can't acquire environment lock after 0 ms.

 Lock owner info: 
Private property of Exodus: 6429@momo.local

jetbrains.exodus.io.LockingManager.lock(LockingManager.java:108)
jetbrains.exodus.io.LockingManager.lock(LockingManager.java:56)
jetbrains.exodus.io.FileDataWriter.lock(FileDataWriter.kt:97)
jetbrains.exodus.log.Log.tryLock(Log.kt:796)
jetbrains.exodus.log.Log.<init>(Log.kt:120)
jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:142)
jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:121)
jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:105)
jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newInstance(Environments.java:60)
kotlinx.dnq.store.container.EntityStoreHelperKt.createTransientEntityStore(EntityStoreHelper.kt:33)
kotlinx.dnq.store.container.StaticStoreContainer.init(StaticStoreContainer.kt:36)
kotlinx.dnq.store.container.StaticStoreContainer.init$default(StaticStoreContainer.kt:35)
uk.ac.kcl.mplatt.ridesharing.UnclosedTest.<init>(UnclosedTest.kt:17)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:117)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

jetbrains.exodus.ExodusException: Can't acquire environment lock after 0 ms.

 Lock owner info: 
Private property of Exodus: 6429@momo.local

jetbrains.exodus.io.LockingManager.lock(LockingManager.java:108)
jetbrains.exodus.io.LockingManager.lock(LockingManager.java:56)
jetbrains.exodus.io.FileDataWriter.lock(FileDataWriter.kt:97)
jetbrains.exodus.log.Log.tryLock(Log.kt:796)
jetbrains.exodus.log.Log.<init>(Log.kt:120)
jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:142)
jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:121)
jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:105)
jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newInstance(Environments.java:60)
kotlinx.dnq.store.container.EntityStoreHelperKt.createTransientEntityStore(EntityStoreHelper.kt:33)
kotlinx.dnq.store.container.StaticStoreContainer.init(StaticStoreContainer.kt:36)
kotlinx.dnq.store.container.StaticStoreContainer.init$default(StaticStoreContainer.kt:35)
uk.ac.kcl.mplatt.ridesharing.UnclosedTest.<init>(UnclosedTest.kt:17)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:117)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at jetbrains.exodus.log.Log.tryLock(Log.kt:797)
    at jetbrains.exodus.log.Log.<init>(Log.kt:120)
    at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:142)
    at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:121)
    at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.java:105)
    at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newInstance(Environments.java:60)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.PersistentEntityStores.newInstance(PersistentEntityStores.java:64)
    at uk.ac.kcl.mplatt.ridesharing.UnclosedTest.lock file is removed when store is closed(UnclosedTest.kt:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How do I close and re-open a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in Xodus-DNQ 1.4.446, thanks for noticing.  As a work around, apply `use` function to `store.persistentStore.environment` in addition:

```
store.persistentStore.environment.use {
    store.use {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The bug will be fixed quite soon, and the new version will be published to Maven Central in several days. The work around won't be broken by the new version.